# Pivot some rows to new columns in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm after a pythonic and *pandemic* (from *pandas*, pun not intended =) way to pivot some rows in a dataframe into new columns.

My data has this format:

```
           dof  foo  bar  qux
idxA idxB                    
100  101     1   10   30   50
     101     2   11   31   51
     101     3   12   32   52
     102     1   13   33   53
     102     2   14   34   54
     102     3   15   35   55
200  101     1   16   36   56
     101     2   17   37   57
     101     3   18   38   58
     102     1   19   39   59
     102     2   20   40   60
     102     3   21   41   61
```

The variables `foo`, `bar` and `qux` actually have 3 dimensional coordinates, which I would like to call `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3`, `bar1`, ..., `qux3`. These are identified by the column `dof`. Each row represents one axis in 3D, `dof == 1` is the x axis, `dof == 2` the y axis and `dof == 3` is the z axis.

So, here is the final dataframe I want:

```
           foo1  bar1  qux1  foo2  bar2  qux2  foo3  bar3  qux3
idxA idxB                                                      
100  101     10    30    50    11    31    51    12    32    52
     102     13    33    53    14    34    54    15    35    55
200  101     16    36    56    17    37    57    18    38    58
     102     19    39    59    20    40    60    21    41    61
```

Question is: what is the best way to do that?

---

Here is what I have done.

A code to re-create my dataset in a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[100, 101, 1, 10, 30, 50],
        [100, 101, 2, 11, 31, 51],
        [100, 101, 3, 12, 32, 52],
        [100, 102, 1, 13, 33, 53],
        [100, 102, 2, 14, 34, 54],
        [100, 102, 3, 15, 35, 55],
        [200, 101, 1, 16, 36, 56],
        [200, 101, 2, 17, 37, 57],
        [200, 101, 3, 18, 38, 58],
        [200, 102, 1, 19, 39, 59],
        [200, 102, 2, 20, 40, 60],
        [200, 102, 3, 21, 41, 61],
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['idxA', 'idxB', 'dof', 'foo', 'bar', 'qux'])
df.set_index(['idxA', 'idxB'], inplace=True)
```

Code to do what I would like to do:

```
df2 = df[df.dof == 1].reset_index()[['idxA', 'idxB']]
df2.set_index(['idxA', 'idxB'], inplace=True)
for pivot in [1, 2, 3]:
    df2.loc[:, 'foo%d' % pivot] = df[df.dof == pivot]['foo']
    df2.loc[:, 'bar%d' % pivot] = df[df.dof == pivot]['bar']
    df2.loc[:, 'qux%d' % pivot] = df[df.dof == pivot]['qux']
```

However I'm not too happy with these `.loc` calls and incremental column additions to the dataframe. I thought that `pandas` being awesome as it is would have a neater way of doing that. A one-liner would be super cool.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [**`df.pivot`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```
df = df.pivot(columns='dof')
          foo         bar         qux
dof         1   2   3   1   2   3   1   2   3
idxA idxB
100  101   10  11  12  30  31  32  50  51  52
     102   13  14  15  33  34  35  53  54  55
200  101   16  17  18  36  37  38  56  57  58
     102   19  20  21  39  40  41  59  60  61
```

Now join using [**`df.columns`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html)

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format) #suggested by @YOBEN_S

          foo1  foo2  foo3  bar1  bar2  bar3  qux1  qux2  qux3
idxA idxB
100  101     10    11    12    30    31    32    50    51    52
     102     13    14    15    33    34    35    53    54    55
200  101     16    17    18    36    37    38    56    57    58
     102     19    20    21    39    40    41    59    60    61
```

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format) `  ;-)

Comment: @YOBEN_S Or even the needlessly complicated  `df.columns = df.columns.to_frame().astype(str).sum(1)` :)

Comment: @Ch3steR Sure, no problem ~

Answer (score 3):

You can add `dof` to index and do a `unstack`:

```
new_df = df.set_index('dof',append=True).unstack('dof')
new_df.columns = [f'{x}{y}' for x,y in new_df.columns]
```

Output:

```
           foo1  foo2  foo3  bar1  bar2  bar3  qux1  qux2  qux3
idxA idxB                                                      
100  101     10    11    12    30    31    32    50    51    52
     102     13    14    15    33    34    35    53    54    55
200  101     16    17    18    36    37    38    56    57    58
     102     19    20    21    39    40    41    59    60    61
```

Comment: This is beautiful ! =)